# What's the status of our conversion of tags to Spanish?

Tags: discusión, etiquetas

I believe it was decided that all our tags would be converted to Spanish, but it seems like we're stuck in a halfway state where some are in Spanish and others are in English. To me, this makes the site look very unpolished (like we can't really decide what we're doing). Granted, there are bigger issues to address (very low question rate and participation in general), but I wanted to ask if we were still planning on translating all existing tags to Spanish and how we're approaching that process.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, someone (me?) should get his butt in gear and finish the conversion.  Until then, I invite people to do the migration themselves, and simply re-tag questions that still have English tags.  Users with sufficient rep are of course encouraged to migrate the English tags to their Spanish counterparts.

At least most of the heavily-used tags have been converted (with a few exceptions, that had pending meta discussions on them, if I recall).

I've been very busy lately, preparing for a move, as well as volunteering with a local municipal election campaign, so I probably won't have much time to invest in tag cleanup here personally until mid-November.

Sorry for dropping the ball on that one :(

Comment: Sounds good. No worries, just wanted to see where we were. Can non-mods rename tags? I didn't think they could.

Comment: What about word-usage, meanings-definitions regional-differences? Should those be translated? What do you think?

Comment: They should be translated.  To what, I'm not sure.  I trust your judgment. We can always change it later, if we change our minds, too.

Comment: I did translate the remaining ones, as well as renamed those missing _tildes_.